# Getting the List of registered devices from fcm for my site

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to FCM and mobile coding. This is what I am trying to achieve:-

1. Develop an app to allow users to select some events.
2. I have a site that will loop through the events for users. When an event is close to its start time or some messages were created for
   that event,  I will send a FCM message to all the devices that
   registered to that event.

I am confused on the implementation. This is what I am thinking:

1. When my app starts, I can register for push notification and it will return a devicetoken.
2. When user saves an event I can pass the devicetoken back to the server to re remember it.
3. In my site's code, I have some code to detect if an event is close and sends notification base on the devicetoken linked to
   that event.

   Is this about the right way to code? But if the user restarts the app or restarts the phone, isn't that I will get a new devicetoken? So I need to store some other identifier to identify a user (e.g. google plus user name)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this about the right way to code? But if the user restarts the app or restarts the phone, isn't that I will get a new devicetoken? So I need to store some other identifier to identify a user (e.g. google plus user name)?

Yes it is right, and check the below for the questions:

You need to use `FirebaseInstanceIdService` it is used to handle the creation, rotation, and updating of registration tokens.

To retrieve the token of a device use this:

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

The above token that you get may change in the following situations:

Instance ID is stable except when:

1. App deletes Instance ID
2. App is restored on a new device
3. User uninstalls/reinstall the app
4. User clears app data

Then using this method inside FirebaseInstanceIdService, it will refresh the token whenever any one of the situation happens:

```
    @Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
  // Get updated InstanceID token.
  String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
  Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

 // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
 // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
 // Instance ID token to your app server.
 sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken); 
}
```

After you've obtained the token, you can send it to your app server and store it using your preferred method.

more info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client